# Cannot load JSP files after deployment

Tags: java, jsp, deployment, tomcat7, war

I'm trying to deploy my app on a remote server.

I copied the .war file into `tomcat7/webapps` and restarted tomcat.
It seems that all the files are in place.
When I'm trying to access a simple .css file it works, but when I'm trying to access any .jsp file I'm getting a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error:

---

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.aid.testjsp_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:177)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.aid.testjsp_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

---

And this is the simple jsp test file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>egfgf</title>
</head>
<body>
    Testing
</body>
</html>
```

When I'm changing this file extension to .html it works.

Obviously, the app works locally (on my pc).

Any suggestions?

**Update**

I signed up for a free trial server and tried to deploy my app there.
It worked like magic. I only had to upload the .war file.

So, my guess, and I'm a newbie, is that it might be a tomcat configuration problem?

**Update 2**

I re installed tomcat and the problem was solved.

Comment: Did you define the servlet mapping? Like, for example, if you have a index.jsp file, you need to map the servlet that prepares and forwards to the index.jsp to a path that can be given in your brower (for example map IndexServlet to /index.htm, and let the IndexServlet forward your request to the actual index.jsp file)

Comment: I'm using the default mapping in the web.xml, it works locally so I guess that part is OK.

Comment: Sound like the JSP files are not compiled. Does your work-Directory exists? Has the Tomcat read/write access to that directory? Try to delete the contents of the work-directory and restart the Tomcat.

Comment: It exists. I tried that (again) and it does not solve the problem.